# Как получить потомка по css селектору или html тегу на js

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как получить потомка по css селектору или html тегу

```
<div id="block">
<p class="one"></p>
<p class="two"></p>
<p class="tree"></p>
</div>

var block = document.getElementById('block');
```

Как получить параграф с классом two?
хочу что-то вроде

```
var paragraph = block.children('.two');
```

И конечно такое не сработает
Как такие вещи решаются на чистом js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все элементы нужного класса:

```
el = block.getElementsByClassName("two");
```

Первый элемент нужного класса:

```
    el = block.getElementsByClassName("two")[0];
```

Локальную задачу также решает:

```
el = block.children[1];
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе мужик громаднейшее

Comment: @vetal, если этот ответ помог - кликните галочку в левом-верхнем углу.

Comment: 3 дня с этим мучился, а оказывается всё так просто)

Comment: и да, второй вариант я бы не советовал использовать

Comment: еще есть такой вариант `document.querySelector('#block .two');`

Comment: А почему? он медленнее?

Comment: @vetal, он ищет второго потомка, а не по селектору класса. Под ваш "дефолтный" вариант подходит, но в целом, он делает не то, что требуется по задаче.

Comment: я щас попробовал block.querySelector('.two'); Он тоже работает!

Comment: @vetal, внезапно (нет). `el = block.getElementsByClassName("two");` - берет элемент сохраненный в переменной `block` и ищет в нем элементы (именно элементы, если их будет больше одного, то придется обрабатывать их как массив элементов), если нужно только скажем первого потомка с таким классом, то лучше использовать `el = block.getElementsByClassName("two")[0];`, вариант же `el = document.querySelector('#block .two');` делает ровно то же самое

Comment: @MedvedevDev `querySelector` ищет первый подходящий, `querySelectorAll` ищет коллекцию

Comment: @Rostyslav Kuzmovych, оу, сорри, да, ошибся, хотел написать, что делает то же самое что и `[0]`, но что-то пошло не так, поправлю )

Comment: Добавил развернутый ответ

Comment: Просто я думаю что если ему придётся искать  не во всём документе а в конкретном элементе то выборка будет быстрее. Разве нет?